# Zebra RW420 Malformed status response

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth

I am unable to get the printer status of a Zebra RW420 when connected to it via Bluetooth on an Android (The smartphone and printer are already paired and all the necessary permissions are in the manifest file). I am programming for API 19.
I get the following exception:

```
com.zebra.sdk.comm.ConnectionException: Malformed status response - unable to determine printer status
```

My code where I try and obtain the status is as follows:

```
Connection printer_connection = new BluetoothConnection(printer_address);
printer_connection.open();
if (printer_connection.isConnected())
{
    ZebraPrinter printer = ZebraPrinterFactory.getInstance(PrinterLanguage.ZPL, printer_connection);
    ZebraPrinterLinkOs linkos_printer = ZebraPrinterFactory.createLinkOsPrinter(printer);
    PrinterStatus printer_status = (linkos_printer != null) ? linkos_printer.getCurrentStatus() : printer.getCurrentStatus();//new PrinterStatusZpl(printer_connection);
    if (printer_status.isReadyToPrint)
    {
        // Send print commends
        printer_connection.close();
    }

....
}
```

The

```
ZebraPrinterLinkOs linkos_printer = ZebraPrinterFactory.createLinkOsPrinter(printer);
PrinterStatus printer_status = (linkos_printer != null) ? linkos_printer.getCurrentStatus() : printer.getCurrentStatus();//new PrinterStatusZpl(printer_connection);
```

part is what I got from the Zebra sample code.

When I remove the lines of code that involve the PrinterStatus I am able to send print commands to the RW420 printer from the Android smartphone and labels/qr-codes are printed without any problem.

I need to obtain the status of the printer as I want to display dialog boxes when there is something wrong with the printer, e.g. out-of-paper, etc.

**UPDATE:**
I have also tried sending the ~HS command to the printer which does result in data being sent back but with testing such as having no paper in the printer or leaving the head open the data coming back does not indicate that there is a problem.

Comment: What happens if you comment the `linkos_printer` instantiation and call `printer.getcurrentStatus` directly?

Comment: Exactly the same result. I initially did just try it with only `printer.getCurrentStatus`. linkos_printer is null as the RW420 is not a LinkOsPrinter. I am wondering whether the printer needs to be configured for status using one of the Zebra tools.

Comment: Where you able to resolve the issues?

Answer (score 0):

Try just a `Thread.Sleep` (or android equivalent) for a second and retry a few times.

I get the same on .NET platform with the same error message. It seems it hasn't had time to connect yet.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: I mean just to try again two or three times to see if it works again

Comment: I tried your suggestion. I have `IPrintStatus status = printer.CurrentStatus; Thread.Sleep(5000);` inside a loop that runs 10 times until it gets the status but it never does. When do you call `Thread.Sleep`?